# Update a datatable after clicking on a network node in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app which displays a network and on the table below you can see all the connections netween nodes through edges and the edges' names. I would like to update the datatable to show only the selected node informations when the node is clicked. For example when Iclick on the node "articaine" only the "articaine" connections will be displayed in the table.

```
#dataset
id<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
  label<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
  node<-data.frame(id,label)

  from<-c("articaine","articaine","articaine","articaine","articaine","articaine","articaine","articaine","articaine")
  to<-c("benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli")
  title<-c("SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN3A","SCN3A","SCN3A")

  edge<-data.frame(from,to,title)

#app

#ui.r
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),  # Specify that the Cerulean Shiny theme/template should be used

                # Generate Title Panel at the top of the app
                titlePanel("Network Visualization App"),  

                # Render as a sidebarLayout. Shiny expects that a sidebarPanel() function and a mainPanel() function are present.

                sidebarLayout(

                  # Sidebar section. Can set the width of the sidebar for any value ranging from 1 to 12.

                  sidebarPanel(             
                  ), # End of the sidebar panel code

                  # Define the main panel
                  mainPanel(

                    h3("Network Visualization"),

                    # Plot the network diagram within the main panel. 
                    # Note that visNetworkOutput is not a Shiny package function, but a visNetwork package function.
                    visNetworkOutput("plot2"),
                    fluidRow(
                      DTOutput('tbl')
                    )

                    ) # End of main panel code

                )
)
#server.r
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

server <- function (input, output, session){


  # Use the renderVisNetwork() function to render the network data.

  output$plot2 <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes = node,edge)%>% 


      visOptions(highlightNearest=T, nodesIdSelection = T) %>%

      # Specify that hover interaction and on-screen button navigations are active
      visInteraction(hover = T, navigationButtons = T) %>%

      visIgraphLayout()

  })
  output$tbl = renderDT(
    edge, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
}
```

Comment: It looks like `visGetSelectedNodes()` should allow you to pass the selected nodes to`server` and restrict you datatable.

Comment: useful comment.would be great if I could create exavtly the table I want and not just take the nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution that allows for selection of multiple nodes, and doesn't use `observe`, but is otherwise similar to the solution firmo23 posted. I filter to any edges with selected nodes in either the "to" or "from" column, since it was unclear to me which you were asking for.

Also, some comments on layout: the sidebar and main panel layout is not required. I tend to prefer nesting of `fluidRow()` and `column()` to define the panels explicitly, which I've done below.

```r
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)

#dataset
id<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
label<-c("articaine","benzocaine","etho","esli")
node<-data.frame(id,label)

from<-c("articaine","articaine","articaine",
        "articaine","articaine","articaine",
        "articaine","articaine","articaine")
to<-c("benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli","benzocaine","etho","esli")
title<-c("SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN1A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN2A","SCN3A","SCN3A","SCN3A")

edge<-data.frame(from,to,title)


#app

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Generate Title Panel at the top of the app
  titlePanel("Network Visualization App"),

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           DTOutput('tbl')),
    column(width = 6,
           visNetworkOutput("network")) #note that column widths in a fluidRow should sum to 12
  ),
  fluidRow(column(width = 6), 
           column(width=6, "Click and hold nodes for a second to select additional nodes.")
  )

) #end of fluidPage


server <- function (input, output, session){

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes = node,edge) %>% 
      visOptions(highlightNearest=TRUE, 
                 nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
      #allow for long click to select additional nodes
      visInteraction(multiselect = TRUE) %>%
      visIgraphLayout() %>% 

      #Use visEvents to turn set input$current_node_selection to list of selected nodes
      visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_selection', nodes.nodes);
                ;}")

  })

  #render data table restricted to selected nodes
  output$tbl <- renderDT(
    edge %>% 
      filter((to %in% input$current_node_selection)|(from %in% input$current_node_selection)),
    options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I accept your solution as more completed. Do you know if I can apply the same logic to edges instead of nodes?I opened a Q for this.

Comment: I assume that it is possible - I saw your question last night. My first naive attempt to mirror this solution didn't work last night. I'll try to look more at it again later, if another solution doesn't come along in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: If the node is selected from the drop-down list do you think it is possible for the table to be updated as well?

Comment: Oh, interesting, I had not tested this. It appears that none of the [visEvents](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visNetwork/versions/2.0.4/topics/visEvents) are fired when interacting with the `nodesIdSelection` dropdown. There may not be a _good_ way to do this, but I think it's probably worth a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work like:

```
#ui.r
    library(igraph)
    library(visNetwork)
    library(dplyr)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)
    library(DT)

    ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),  # Specify that the Cerulean Shiny theme/template should be used

                    # Generate Title Panel at the top of the app
                    titlePanel("Network Visualization App"),  

                    # Render as a sidebarLayout. Shiny expects that a sidebarPanel() function and a mainPanel() function are present.

                    sidebarLayout(

                      # Sidebar section. Can set the width of the sidebar for any value ranging from 1 to 12.

                      sidebarPanel(             
                      ), # End of the sidebar panel code

                      # Define the main panel
                      mainPanel(

                        h3("Network Visualization"),

                        # Plot the network diagram within the main panel. 
                        # Note that visNetworkOutput is not a Shiny package function, but a visNetwork package function.
                        visNetworkOutput("plot2"),

                          dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
                          uiOutput('dt_UI')


                        ) # End of main panel code

                    )
    )
    #server.r
    library(igraph)
    library(visNetwork)
    library(dplyr)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)

    server <- function (input, output, session){


      # Use the renderVisNetwork() function to render the network data.

      output$plot2 <- renderVisNetwork({

        visNetwork(nodes,edge)%>% 
          visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                    Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
                    ;}")%>%

          visOptions(highlightNearest=T, nodesIdSelection = T) %>%

          # Specify that hover interaction and on-screen button navigations are active
          visInteraction(hover = T, navigationButtons = T) %>%

          visIgraphLayout()

      })

      myNode <- reactiveValues(selected = '')

      observeEvent(input$current_node_id, {
        myNode$selected <<- input$current_node_id
      })
      output$table <- renderDataTable({
        edge[which(myNode$selected == edge$from),]
      })
      output$dt_UI <- renderUI({
        if(nrow(edge[which(myNode$selected == edge$from),])!=0){
          dataTableOutput('table')
        } else{}

      })
    }
```