# Common input for visNetwork and DT in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt, visnetwork

I am trying to figure out how can I like together visNetwork and DT in Shiny R. I want to use a selected node in the visNetwork as an input for selected row in the DT and vise versa. For example, if a user click on a node in the visNetwork, the corresponding row (by Id of the dataset "data") is selected. The problem is that I struggle to find out how to create an input variable for the visNetwork as well as input and output variables for the DT (and make them reactive).

I have the following code for the visNetwork:

```
renderVisNetwork({
  
    search_input <- input$search_input

    result <- data %>%
      filter(grepl(search_input, Name, ignore.case = TRUE) | 
          grepl(search_input, Abstract, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
    select(Id)

    nodes <- data.frame(
      id = data$Id,
      label = gsub("(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+", "\\1\n", data$Name),
      color = ifelse(data$Id %in% result$Id & input$search_input != "", "#f7bf05", NA)
    )
    
    edges_citation <- data.frame(
      from = data$Citation1,
      to = data$Id
    )
    
    all_edges <- rbind(edges_citation)
    
    network <- visNetwork(nodes, all_edges) %>% 
    visEvents(
      click = "function(nodes) {
        var selectedNodeId = nodes.nodes[0]; // Get the selected node ID
        Shiny.setInputValue('selectedNodeId', selectedNodeId); // Set the input value for Shiny
      }"
    )
    
    hey <- reactive({
      selected_data <- input$selectedNodeId
      return(selected_data)
    })

output$selectedNodeId = renderText({
      hey()
    })
    
    network
  })
```

And I have the following code for the DT:

```
output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  search_input <- input$search_input

    result <- data %>%
      filter(grepl(search_input, Name, ignore.case = TRUE) | 
          grepl(search_input, Abstract, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
    select(Id)
  
  data_render_id <- data %>% 
  filter(Id %in% result$Id) %>% 
  select(Id, Name, Authors, Year)
  
  
  data_render <- data_render_id %>% 
    select(-Id)

  data_render_output <- DT::datatable(data_render)
  
    idfinaly <- reactive({
      selected_data <- input$data_table_rows_selected
      selected_id <- data_render_id$Id[selected_data]
      selected_id_reactive(selected_id) 
      return(selected_id)
    })
    
    output$selectedRowId <- renderText({
      idfinaly()
    })

  data_render_output})

DTOutput("data_table")
```

P.S. This is a Flexdashboard application, therefore I did no apply ui/server logic here.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480210/update-a-datatable-after-clicking-on-a-network-node-in-a-shiny-app